# Error installing wine on OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine

I'm trying to install wine on Mac OS X 10.9.5, but I'm getting some kind of error.
Here is output after

```
brew install wine

==> Installing dependencies for wine: fontconfig, libtiff, gd, libgphoto2, little-cms2, jasper, libicns, makedepend, openssl, sane-backends
==> Installing wine dependency: fontconfig
==> Downloading http://fontconfig.org/release/fontconfig-2.11.1.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fontconfig-2.11.1.tar.bz2
==> Patching
patching file fc-cache/fc-cache.c
patching file fontconfig/fontconfig.h
patching file src/fccache.c
patching file src/fcdir.c
patching file src/fcfs.c
patching file src/fcint.h
patching file src/fcpat.c
==> ./configure --disable-silent-rules --with-add-fonts=/System/Library/Fonts,/Library/Fonts,~/Library/Fonts --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc
==> make install RUN_FC_CACHE_TEST=false
make[2]: *** [install-data-local] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fonts.dtd '/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/share/xml/fontconfig'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
```

Now I'm not much familiar with brew but if someone can point me on the right track I would appreciate it very much.

Btw, the single reason I'm trying to install wine is so that I can play Civilization3 on OSX.

Comment: Did you read the last four lines of the error messages you posted? They explain pretty clearly what the problem is and how to resolve it, and also provides a link (conveniently marked as **READ THIS**) to troubleshooting information.

Comment: I did brew doctor and I tried installing wine via port but it also failed. In the end, I'm thinking giving up the whole thing since I tried Civ3 on Linux via wine and it failed on startup...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about troubleshooting software problems, as opposed to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I installed wine via [wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php).